# Using Multiple Solr Analyser in the same Schema

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, full-text-search, xsd

In regards to Schema.xml. How does Solr know the which analyser/tokenizer to use?

I'm getting the data from mysql and have the parameters set up on db-data-config.xml. What I dont understand is once the solr gets the metadata from the database, how does Solr use schema to index the data? How does it know which data is specified by which field?

(I'm new to solr)

In short: I'm not sure how the db-data-config.xml links with schema.xml. Since in db-data-config.xml I only specify the column and name attributes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: open the schema.xml and try to find the fields that are referred to with names in the db-data-config.xml. Do see them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema file contains both field type definitions (these are the tokenizer/filter/char-filter chains) for both index time and query time , and fields , each of the fields pointing to a field type.